# Appending rows to a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to achieve the below for a spark a dataframe. I want to keep appending new rows to a dataframe as shown in the below example.

```
for(a<- value)
        { 
         val num = a
         val count = a+10
         //creating a df with the above values//
         val data = Seq((num.asInstanceOf[Double], count.asInstanceOf[Double]))
         val row = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("Number","count")
         val data2 =  data1.union(row)
         val data1 = data2 --> currently this assignment is not possible.
         }
```

I have also tried

```
for(a<- value)
        { 
         val num = a
         val count = a+10
         //creating a df with the above values//
         val data = Seq((num.asInstanceOf[Double], count.asInstanceOf[Double]))
         val row = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("Number","count")
         val data1 =  data1.union(row) --> Union with self is not possible
         }
```

How can I achieve this in spark.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframes are immutable, you will need to use mutable structure. Here is the solution that might help you.

```
scala> val value = Array(1.0, 2.0, 55.0)
value: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 2.0, 55.0)

scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

scala> var data = new ListBuffer[(Double, Double)]
data: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Double, Double)] = ListBuffer()

scala> for(a <- value)
     | {
     | val num = a
     | val count = a+10
     | data += ((num.asInstanceOf[Double], count.asInstanceOf[Double]))
     | println(data)
     | }
ListBuffer((1.0,11.0))
ListBuffer((1.0,11.0), (2.0,12.0))
ListBuffer((1.0,11.0), (2.0,12.0), (55.0,65.0))

scala> val DF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("Number","count")
DF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Number: double, count: double]

scala> DF.show()
+------+-----+
|Number|count|
+------+-----+
|   1.0| 11.0|
|   2.0| 12.0|
|  55.0| 65.0|
+------+-----+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `data1` must be declared as `var`:

```
var data1:DataFrame = ???

for(a<- value)
{
  val num = a
  val count = a+10
  //creating a df with the above values//
  val data = Seq((num.toDouble, count.toDouble))
  val row = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("Number","count")
  val data2 =  data1.union(row)
  data1 = data2 
}
```

But I would not suggest to do this, better convert your entire `value` (must be a `Seq`?) to a dataframe, then union once. Many unions tend to be inefficient....

```
val newDF = value.toDF("Number")
  .withColumn("count",$"Number" + 10)

val result= data1.union(newDF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create one DataFrame using the for-loop and then union with `data1` like this:

```
val df = ( for(a <- values) yield (a, a+10) ).toDF("Number", "count")
val result = data1.union(df)
```

This would be much more efficient than doing unions inside the for-loop.